Understanding the gcc related recipes in Yocto project

I am trying to understand how exactly the concpet of toolchain for embedded Linux systems is used/being practiced in the Yocto project but find myself
confused.
To start with, what I DO understand about toolchains in embedded systems in general (not necessarly in Yocto project's context), is that a toolchain, high level speaking, is a set of
tools (utilities), libraries, configurations, etc... that are used to build at the "first phase", the requiered "system" software that will be
deployed and used on the target machine i.e.- the Linux kernel, relevant/requiered kernel modules (in source-tree), glibc (or some other C library) - which acts as an interface
between the kernel and user space applications, while also, and perhapse at a later stage, i.e. - at the "second phase", the toolchain will be used
to build all sort of other packages (3rd party or propraietry) and some user space applications (for example, some propraietry C/C++ user space application
that runs and display to the console "Hello World!"). The separation for these two phases allows to have several teams to work on the embedded system in parrallel (i.e. - the first phase is typically done by some BSP/OS team and the application development that are hosted on the OS, are done, typically, by another team, during the second phase).
Typical tools of a toolchain are usually (not limited to): gcc/g++, binutils, and some other "build related" utilities. In addition there are also the kernel headers
and glibc.
When dealing with toolchains, there is the concpet of cross-compilation off course, for example, host is X86_64 architecture based and target is ARM architecture based.
In my case, I perform cross-compilation by having the host machine as an X86_64 machine with Ubuntu 20.04 (with gcc 9.4.0 and glibc 2.31) and the target
machine ALSO being an X86_64 with some other Linux flavor that will be used (Debian based, but not Ubuntu).
In my Yocto version (mickledore) I use, under the layers/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/ folder, there are (in addition to others that are not mentioed)
the following recipes:
gcc-cross-canadian.inc    gcc-crosssdk.inc            gcc_12.3.bb             
gcc-12.3.inc              gcc-cross-canadian_12.3.bb  gcc-crosssdk_12.3.bb     
gcc-common.inc            gcc-cross.inc                
gcc-configure-common.inc  gcc-cross_12.3.bb  

My intuition tells me these recipes are divided as follows:

gcc-12.3* - are responsible for building the gcc that will be deployed and hosted on the target machine (if it is relevant offcourse, because many, if not all embedded system are not meant to act as a host/build machine).

gcc-cross* - are responsible for building the gcc that will be used for cross compilation, just like in my case (in which the host and target machine
even though are both X86_64, are not the same machine - so the cross compiler is needed).
gcc-cross-canadian* - are responsible for building the gcc that will be used for cross compilation in the case of cross-canadian build.
gcc-cross-sdk* - are responsible for building the gcc that will be used for cross compilation for other applications that will be built using the
SDK that Yocto can provide (i.e. - when I will build my image as follows: bitbake <my_image> -c populate_sdk).

One of the features (advantages) of the Yocto project as an holistic "build system" is that during the build of some image, Yocto first builds its own toolchain that will be used to
build (mainly compile) the packages that will be installed on the image's root file system.
When examining the BitBake logs during the build, and grep-ing for do_compile, indeed the first packages I see that are being built are packages that are
related/part of a toolchain, such as: gcc, glibc, autoconf, kern-tools, pkconfig, patch and many more, while only at a later stage, other "concrete"
packages (i.e. - that are running on the target system, for example, openssh) and propraietry applications are being built.
This offcourse, make sense due to the above feature of Yocto project that was mentioned eariler.
Taking into account the following, my questions are:

Are my assumptions about the role of the different gcc-xxx recipes is correct? If not, what is wrong?

When further examining the BitBake logs during the build, and grep-ing for do_compile, I noticed that when I build the image itself, i.e. - when I
run the command:bitbake <my_image>, I see BitBake tasks for the gcc and gcc-cross recipes. However, when I do the same for the SDK for this image, i.e. -
when I run the command: bitbake <my_image> -c populate_sdk - I see BitBake tasks for the gcc-crosssdk, gcc-cross-canadian and gcc-cross recipes.
If the gcc-cross is being built during the actual image creation, why is it ALSO being built for the SDK? What is the differece between the
gcc-cross and gcc-crosssdk? I would expect that during the SDK creation only the gcc-cross-canadian and gcc-crosssdk will be built.

For the binutils, which is also a mandatory package for the build procedure, I also see recipes for cross, crosssdk and cross-canadian, like for the
gcc tool. However, when looking at the BitBake build logs, for both the actual image and the SDK, in both cases I see tasks that are related only for
the binutils-cross and binutils BUT NOT of the binutils-crosssdk - why is it different from the gcc case?

If I do not wish to have the gcc executable (and other related "artifacts" of the gcc recipe) to be part of my final image, how do I remove it? When I simply tried IMAGE_INSTALL_REMOVE += "gcc" --> did not have any impact (i.e., the gcc executable and the other related files are still present on my image root file system).


